# Distinct Values in SQL Query - Advanced

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have searched high and low and have tried for hours to manipulate the various other queries that seemed to fit but I've had no joy.

I have several Tables in Microsoft SQL Server 2005 that I'm trying to join, an example of which is:

```
Company Table (Comp_CompanyId, Comp_Name)
GroupCode_Link Table (gcl_c_groupcodelinkid, gcl_c_groupcodeid, gcl_c_companyid)
GroupCode Table (grp_c_groupcodeid, grp_c_groupcode, grp_c_name)
ItemCode Table (itm_c_itemcodeid, itm_c_name, itm_c_itemcode, itm_c_group)
ItemCode_Link Table (icl_c_itemcodelinkid, icl_c_companyid, icl_c_groupcodeid, icl_c_itemcodeid)
```

I'm using Link Tables to associate a Group to a Company, and an Item to a Group, so a Company could have multiple groups, with multiple items in each group.

Now, I'm trying to create an Advanced Find Function that will allow a user to enter, for example, an Item Code and the result should display those companies that have that item, sounds nice and simple!

However, I haven't done something right, if I use the following query ' if the company has this item OR this item, display it's name', I get the company appearing twice in the result set, once for each item.

What I need is to be able to say is:

"Show me a list of companies that have these items (displaying each company only once!)"

I've had a go at using COUNT, DISTINCT and HAVING but have failed on each as my query knowledge isn't up to it!

Answer (score 2):

First, from your description it sounds like you might have a problem with your E-R (entity-relationship) model. Your description tells me that your E-R model looks something like this:

[image: original E-R model]

**Associative entities** (CompanyGroup, GroupItem) exist to implement many-to-many relationships (since many-to-many isn't supported directly by relational databases).

Nothing wrong with that if a group can exist within multiple companies or an item across multiple groups. It would seem more likely that, at least, each group is specific to a company (I can see items existing across multiple companies and/or groups: more than one company retails, for instance, Cuisinart food processors). If that is the case, a better E-R model would be to make each group a **dependent entity** with a CompanyID that is a component of its primary key. It's a dependent entity because the group doesn't have an independent existence: it's created by/on behalf of and exists for its parent company. If the company goes away, the group(s) tied to it go away. No your E-R model looks like this:

[image: simplified E-R model]

From that, we can write the query you need:

```
select *
from Company c
where exists ( select *
               from GroupItem gi
               where gi.ItemID in ( desired-itemid-1 , ... , desired-itemid-n )
                 and gi.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
             )
```

As you can see, dependent entities are a powerful thing. Because of the key propagation, queries tend to get simpler. With the original data model, the query would be somewhat more complex:

```
select *
from Company c
where exists ( select *
               from CompanyGroup cg
               join GroupItem    gi on gi.GroupId = cg.GroupID
               where gi.ItemID in ( desired-itemid-1 , ... , desired-itemid-n )
                 and cg.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
             )
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    company c
WHERE   (
        SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT icl_c_itemcodeid)
        FROM    GroupCode_Link gl
        JOIN    ItemCode_Link il
        ON      il.icl_c_groupcodeid = gcl_c_groupcodeid
        WHERE   gl.gcl_c_companyid = c.Comp_CompanyId
                AND icl_c_companyid = c.Comp_CompanyId
                AND icl_c_itemcodeid IN (@Item1, @Item2)
        ) >= 2
```

Replace `>= 2` with `>= 1` if you want "any item" instead of "all items".

Comment: From a performance perspective, for "any item", wouldn't it make sense to use 'exist' instead of 'count'? If these were massive tables wouldn't count be significantly slower?

Comment: @kevev22: `SQL Server` optimizes `COUNT(*) >= 1`, `EXISTS` and `IN` to the same plan.

Comment: And you would have to replace '= 2' with '>= 1' for any item.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show companies that have item1 AND item2, you can use Quassnoi's answer.

If you need to show companies that have item1 OR item2, then you can use this:

```
SELECT  
   *
FROM    
   company
WHERE EXISTS 
(
   SELECT
      icl_c_itemcodeid
   FROM
      GroupCode_Link
   INNER JOIN
      ItemCode_Link 
         ON icl_c_groupcodeid = gcl_c_groupcodeid
         AND icl_c_itemcodeid IN (@item1, @item2)
   WHERE   
      gcl_c_companyid = company.Comp_CompanyId
   AND 
      icl_c_companyid = company.Comp_CompanyId
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like the code below:

```
SELECT
    c.Comp_Name
FROM
    Company AS c
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            GroupCode_Link AS gcl
        JOIN
            ItemCode_Link AS icl
        ON
            gcl.gcl_c_groupcodeid = icl.icl_c_groupcodeid
        JOIN
            ItemCode AS itm
        ON
            icl.icl_c_itemcodeid = itm.itm_c_itemcodeid
        WHERE
            c.Comp_CompanyId = gcl.gcl_c_companyid
        AND
            itm.itm_c_itemcode IN (...) /* here provide list of one or more Item Codes to look for */
    );
```

but I see there's a icl_c_companyid column in the ItemCode_Link so using GroupCode_Link table is not necessary?